# Função com if JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Boa Tarde, estou com uma função no javascript, e ele não entra no IF, o campo txtTipodePlano está preenchido como "MENSAL", ele deveria entrar, só que ele cai no else, segue como estou fazendo:

```js
if (document.getElementById("<%=ckPosPago.ClientID%>").checked) {
  var t = document.getElementById('txtTipodePlano').value;
  if (t == "MENSAL") {
    now = new Date;
    var dia_atual = now.getDate();
    var atual_data = toDate(document.getElementById("<%= txtDataInicio.ClientID %>").value);
    var dia_escolha = document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>").value;

    function toDate(atual_data) {
      let partes = atual_data.split('/');
      return new Date(partes[2], partes[1], partes[0]);
    }
    if (parseInt(dia_escolha) > parseInt(dia_atual)) {
      var data_tolerancia;
      var total_dias = dia_escolha - dia_atual;
      atual_data.setDate(atual_data.getDate() + parseInt(total_dias));
      document.getElementById("<%= txtVencimentoC.ClientID %>").value = atual_data.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      var tol = (document.getElementById("<%= txtToleranca.ClientID %>").value);
      atual_data.setDate(atual_data.getDate() + parseInt(tol));
      document.getElementById("<%= txtDataTolerancia.ClientID %>").value = atual_data.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    } else {
      var data_tolerancia;
      var total_dias = dia_escolha - dia_atual;
      atual_data.setDate(atual_data.getDate() + parseInt(total_dias));
      document.getElementById("<%= txtVencimentoC.ClientID %>").value = atual_data.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      var tol = (document.getElementById("<%= txtToleranca.ClientID %>").value);
      atual_data.setDate(atual_data.getDate() + parseInt(tol));
      document.getElementById("<%= txtDataTolerancia.ClientID %>").value = atual_data.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
  } else {
    function toDate(data) {
      let partes = data.split('/');
      return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
    }
    var atual_data1 = toDate(document.getElementById("<%= txtDataFim.ClientID %>").value);
    document.getElementById("<%= txtVencimentoC.ClientID %>").value = atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    var tol = (document.getElementById("<%= txtToleranca.ClientID %>").value);
    atual_data1.setDate(atual_data1.getDate() + parseInt(tol));
    document.getElementById("<%= txtDataTolerancia.ClientID %>").value = atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    document.getElementById("<%= txtpropor.ClientID %>").value = null;
  }
}
```

Esse é como está o txt:

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTipodePlano" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Ele entra certo no ckPosPago, só que não entra no t == "MENSAL". 
Já pesquisei, mudei várias vezes, mas nenhuma ele entra no IF, agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
document.getElementById('txtTipodePlano').value;
```

Quando você cria um control com `runat="server"`, o id dele vai mudar, a não ser que tenha `ClientIDMode="Static"`. Portanto, ele não encontrou o valor correto, e por isso nunca é igual à "MENSAL"

Para corrigir, troque esta linha:

```
var t = document.getElementById('txtTipodePlano').value;
```

por essa:

```
var t = document.getElementById("<%= txtTipodePlano.ClientID %>").value;
```

Recomendo que você aprenda a debuggar seus códigos, tanto Javascript como no server side. 
Uma ferramenta útil é o comando `debugger`. Coloque ele logo acima da linha aonde deseja debuggar, e mantenha o console aberto, e a execução de Javascript irá parar ali

Comment: Artur, deu certo, ele entra no if, só que agora estou com um problema ao passar o valor para um textbox, ele informa que está null. Poderia me ajudar?